# How Do I Run IntelliJ IDEA 9 as a 64-bit Process?

Tags: java, 64-bit, intellij-idea

I've noticed that IntelliJ IDEA 9 runs as a 32-bit process in Windows 2003 x64 and would like to configure it to run as a 64-bit process. I did find [an article](http://lajosd.blogspot.com/2009/10/mac-os-x-using-intellij-idea-on-64bit.html) about how to perform this in Mac OSX, but not in Windows.

*Update #1:* I have the 64-bit version of JDK 1.6.18 installed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This post](http://jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-1185) might help.  It mentions using an `idea64.exe` launcher on Windows.

Comment: Great stuff. Downloaded the file, set the IDEA_JDK environment variable and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to create an idea64.exe.vmoptions file.  This link to previous versions of Idea might also be helpful for some:  http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1228

Answer (score 1):

My wild guess, is that you only need a 64 bit JDK/JRE and that's it.

Download the x64 version:

[JDK x64 windows http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/8004/capturadepantalla201001u.png](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/8004/capturadepantalla201001u.png)

And then configure IntellJ IDEA to use it.

This [guide](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/08/running-mustang/) shows how what to change to set own JDK ( although is a bit dated and things may have changed as of now )

> *The environment variable* IDEA_JDK *or* JDK_HOME *should be set to point to the location where JDK 1.6.0 is installed*

Comment: Again without further substantiation, I would have said so too.

Comment: I already have that installed, but IDEA still shows as a 32-bit process. ("idea.exe*32")

Comment: Yeap, you have to tell IDEA that you want to use a different jdk ( see the guide, it should be the same still )

Answer (score 0):

Install jdk 64 bit and setting of 'set IDEA_JDK home is enough.
Once this variable is set you could use